# Can't target method inside other component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

How to target method inside other component?

I'm working on a project where I want to target a method inside another component. I press a button inside the dashboard component and I want to change the data inside my line-chart component (which uses `vue-chartjs`). How can I target this method?

Comment: You have to show some code before we can help

Comment: Here is the psuedo code of my problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/ycck7cwb/

Comment: Please include the code in the question, not as an external link.

Answer (score 0):

You can call children's method by referencing them through [refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Child-Component-Refs)

In your example, your dashboard's template should looks like this :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="$refs.chart.yourMethod()">Call child method</button>
    <line-chart ref="chart"></line-chart>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could target it over `$refs` however, this is pretty dirty, as it prodvides a pretty strict binding of your componentes.

A better solution would be to trigger an event (eventbus) or over an prop.